# $x^4=x$ commutative ring.

Tags: ring-theory

Q: if $R$ is a ring such that for every $x\in R$ , $x^4=x$, then prove $R$ is commutative.

What I've tried:
First we notice that
$-x=(-x)^4=x^4=x$.

$x+x=2x=0$

Then we can show that $x^2+x$ is is a central because $(x^2+x)^2=x^4+2x^3+x^2=x^2+x$

($x^2+x$ is idempotent)

Now I can't proceed from here.
:(
Any help is much appreciated!